# MatSelect not updating selected value accordingly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working on an application that allows a user to assign an artist to a given release and an artist to given songs within that release. These two given sections are separated using the MatTab component.

I am trying to make it so that when a user selects an artist for the parent release, that same artist is selected on the next tab for adding songs, as that would be the most common scenario (even though I'll probably be the only one using this). I've tried many different configurations and cannot seem to get this working.

---

Here is the root release form.  The artist form for the release is under the details tab.  Into that I am passing the root release form, an observable array of artists from the API, and a method to handle the event emitter.  When the artist form for the release is changed it is emitted and the subject is updated.

The artist form for individual songs is a child of the app-track-subform component in the "Tracks & Artwork" tab.  Note that I am passing in a subject of the currently selected artist.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="form">
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <mat-tab-group>
            <mat-tab label="Details">
                <app-title-subform [form]="form"></app-title-subform>
                <app-artist-subform [form]="form" [artists$]="artists$" (selectArtist)="selectReleaseArtist($event)"></app-artist-subform>
                <app-release-type-subform [form]="form"></app-release-type-subform>
            </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="Tracks & Artwork">
                <app-image-subform  [form]="artworkFormGroup"></app-image-subform>
                <app-track-subform [currentReleaseArtist]="releaseArtist" [form]="form" [artists$]="artists$" (addNewTrack)="addNewTrack($event)"></app-track-subform>
                <app-tracks-subform [tracks]="tracksFormArray"></app-tracks-subform>
            </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="Submission">
                <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="secondary">Submit</button>
            </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
    </form>
</ng-container>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormArray , FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { BaseReleaseForm } from 'src/helpers';
import { IArtist } from 'src/models';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/api.service';
import { ArtistSubformComponent } from '../subforms/shared/artist-subform/artist-subform.component';
import { TrackSubformComponent } from '../subforms/track-subform/track-subform.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-release-root-form',
  templateUrl: './release-root-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./release-root-form.component.css']
})
export class ReleaseRootFormComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  @Output() submitEmitter : EventEmitter<FormGroup> = new EventEmitter();
  artists$? : Observable<IArtist[]>;
  releaseArtist? : Subject<IArtist> = new Subject();

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private api: ApiService) { 
    this.form = BaseReleaseForm(fb);
  }
  get tracksFormArray() : FormArray {
    return this.form.controls['tracks'] as FormArray;
  }
  get currentTrack() : FormGroup {
    const index = this.tracksFormArray.controls.length - 1;
    return this.tracksFormArray.controls[index] as FormGroup;
  }
  get artworkFormGroup() : FormGroup {
    return this.form?.controls['artwork'] as FormGroup;
  }
  get artistFormGroup() : FormGroup {
    return this.form?.controls['artist'] as FormGroup;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.artists$ = this.api.getArtists();
  }

  selectReleaseArtist(artist: IArtist) {
    this.releaseArtist?.next(artist);
  }

  handleTrackChange(submitted : boolean) {
    if (!submitted) {
      const index = this.tracksFormArray.controls.indexOf(this.currentTrack);
      this.tracksFormArray.removeAt(index);
    }
  }

  addNewTrack(trackForm: FormGroup) {
    if (trackForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    this.tracksFormArray.push(trackForm);
  }

  onSubmit() : void {
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    this.submitEmitter.emit(this.form);
  }
}
```

---

Here is the artist subform which is used for both the release and the form to add a song.
The changes from the root are being successfully passed down to the child (see the ngAfterViewInit method), so I'm not sure what I am missing here.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material/select';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/api.service';
import { IArtist } from 'src/models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-artist-subform',
  templateUrl: './artist-subform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./artist-subform.component.css']
})
export class ArtistSubformComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() currentReleaseArtist? : Subject<IArtist>;
  @Input() form? : FormGroup;
  @Input() artists$? : Observable<IArtist[]>;
  @Output() selectArtist : EventEmitter<IArtist> = new EventEmitter();
  releaseArtist?: IArtist;
  
  constructor(private api : ApiService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() : void {
    this.currentReleaseArtist?.subscribe(x => {
       this.releaseArtist = x;
       console.log(this.releaseArtist);
    });
  }
  
  onChange(artist : IArtist) {
    this.selectArtist.emit(artist);
  }
}
```

```
<ng-container *ngIf="form && artists$">
    <form [formGroup]="form">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Artist</mat-label>
            <mat-select matInput formControlName="artist" [(ngModel)]="releaseArtist" (selectionChange)="onChange($event.value)">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let artist of artists$ | async" [value]="artist">
                    {{ artist.name }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>
</ng-container>
```

---

And here are my form groups

```
export function BaseReleaseForm(fb: FormBuilder, release? : IRelease | undefined) : FormGroup {
    return fb.group({
        type: ['', Validators.required],
        title: ['', Validators.required],
        tracks: new FormArray([]),
        artist: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        artwork: fb.group({
            file: [null, Validators.required]
        })
    })
}

export function BaseTrackForm(fb: FormBuilder) : FormGroup {
    return fb.group({
        type: ['', Validators.required],
        title: ['', Validators.required],
        file: [null, [Validators.required]],
        artist: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        artwork: fb.group({
            file: [null, Validators.required]
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: don't use for formControlName & ngModel in one control

Comment: I originally had it without ngModel and I am still getting the same results either way